# Can't add new MySQL dataconnection VS2010

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to add an new Data Connection in Visual Studio 2010, but every time i trye to enter an ip adresse to my MySQL server. The dialog box disappears without giving me any reason ore error messages. Has any seen this problem before ore heard any solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an solution to the problem. 
It was to uninstall and reinstall the MySQL Connector with the neweste version. To other with the same problem an site talking about the problem [can be found here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55623). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Basically, every time I opened Visual Studio 2010 and tried to add a MySQL Connection, the dialog would disappear after you type one letter in any field. I tried various things, including re-installing Visual Studio, the MySQL Connector and MySQL Server itself several times, nothing fixed the problem.

However, I also had Visual Studio 2008 installed, and I noticed I could add MySQL connections without any hassle at all, but this didn't help since the project was in VS2010. This made me think it had to be an issue with the way Framework 4.0 had been installed on my machine. To cut a long story short, this is how I resolved the issue:

1) Navigate to the Framework 4 folder ('C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config' in my case)

2) Open the machine.config file and look for the `<DbProviderFactories>` tags under the `<system.data>` section.

3) Here, I noticed a difference to how Framework 2.0 was set up. In 4.0, there were two sets of `<DbProviderFactories>` tags whereas 2.0 had one.

4) All I did was merge everything under one set of `<DbProviderFactories>` tags by deleting the `</DbProviderFactories><DbProviderFactories>` in the middle.

5) I saved the machine.config file (which by the way, i had to save to another directory and then copy and paste over the original), restarted Visual Studio 2010 and the dialog box stopped disappearing.

Hope this helps anyone facing a similar problem. Spent 3 days trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - the Data Connections -> Add Connection dialog disappearing after I type one character - but only for MySQL. In my researching I came across a posting (I don't know where anymore - sorry) that it had something to do with IIS authentication. I had IIS in Control Panel->Programs and features but not in Administrative tools. From further research, I got the sense that I needed to activate IIS on a new(ish) PC. The following page gave the instructions for that. I had to scroll down to the Win 8 section.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh167503%28v=nav.70%29.aspx

After these steps I was able to see IIS in Administrative tools and to properly fill in the Data Connections -> Add Connection dialog in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i gave you the simple solution. I have same issue and it waste my lot of time. i gave you simple solution you first install Microsoft .NET Framework Version 1.1 Redistributable Package      from here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26

and after that you Download Connector/Net   from here

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

after that restart the visual studio and then connect the database you fill get no error or bug.

Please try this one if you have same issue.